# Programa para calcular potencias usando while en C# (Windows Form)

Tags: c#, windows-forms, while

tengo que hacer un programa que calcule las potencias de los números ingresados por el usuario.
El problema es que obligatoriamente tengo que hacerlo utilizando el ciclo while y realmente no sé cuál debe ser mi condicionante que vaya dentro del while.
Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Tu `while` debe estar condicionado por el número al que queires elevar la base

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de información como que has probado o que has encontrado por Internet, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Answer (score 0):

tenes que multiplicar mientras(while) el número de multiplicaciones sea menor o igual a la potencia que te ingresaron

```
private int potencia;//cuanto lo queres elevar
private int total;//donde se va a guardar
private int var;//numero base

//aca te ingresan los valores

total = 1;
while(int cont <= potencia)
{
   total = total * var;
   cont ++;
}
//despues mostras total
```

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la respuesta agregando algo de información, y sería bueno que realices el [tour]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas tanto en la respuesta como en la pregunta.

Comment: Así está bien? perdón era mi primera respuesta, no pense que necesitase código para responder una duda conceptual

Comment: No pasa nada, iras aprendiendo poco a poco como funciona el sitio, por ejemplo, esta pregunta es de baja calidad. El usuario no a mostrado ningún ejemplo y no parece que haya perdido mucho tiempo buscando por Internet. Este tipo de preguntas no se suele responder y se reportan.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías platear el problema de la siguiente forma:

resultado = 1   -> Este va ha ser el valor del resultado, inicia con 1 y no con cero para no resulte cero al hallar la potencia.

potencia = ? -> seria el valor del exponente del numero que se desea hallar la respuesta.

numero = ? -> valor del numero de la base de la potencia

luego en el while:

resultado = 1
potencia = 3   //valor de ejemplo
numero = 5   //valor de ejemplo
inicio = 0   //para resolver el while

while(inicio < potencia){
//compara el valor de inicio con el de potencia para validar el while
 resultado = resultado * numero; // opera la potencia
 inicio = inicio +1; //aumenta al 1 al inicio para que el while tenga fin
}

Luego de operar el while,la potencia se encontraría en la variable "resultado"